# The double dual space of the set of all infinite binary sequences with finitely many 1's

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$ with basis $ e_k=(0,.. 0, 1, 0, ...)$, with 1 in the k-th position. Define the dual vectors $e_k^*$, with $e_k^*(e_j)=\delta_{k,j}$(the Kronecker delta).

Prove that there is a linear functional $\in V^{**}$ (the double dual space) such that $f(e_k^*)=1, \forall k \geq 1$

Comment: Is that one functional for each $k$, or one functional over all $k$?

Comment: Since the set $\{e_k^*,\ k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is l.i. you can extend it to form a basis of $V^*$ and now you can choose $f\in V^{**}$ to be equal to $1$ on every element of this basis.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the underlying field and let $E=(e_k)_k$ be the considered basis of $V$. Every function $E\rightarrow K$ gives birth (by linearity) to an element of $V^*$ and the converse is true.

Note that an element of $V$ is a function $E\rightarrow K$ that is zero almost everywhere. From this point, we can show that $card(V)<card(V^*)$.

Let $F\supset ({e_k}*)_k$ be a basis of $V^*$. As above, every function $F\rightarrow K$ gives birth (by linearity) to an element of $V^{**}$ and the converse is true. Done.